# How to remove non-loop vertices in a graph?

Tags: functions, function-construction, graphs-and-networks

How can I remove vertices from a graph that do not form a loop? 
For example,

```
graph = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1, 4 <-> 5, 1 <-> 6, 5 <-> 7}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

The expected result would be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`KCoreComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KCoreComponents.html)

```
Subgraph[graph, KCoreComponents[graph, 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, probably couldn't be simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I just found a way to do it. I'm still curious if there are other approaches or better improvements for my code, though.

```
graph = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1, 4 <-> 5, 1 <-> 6, 5 <-> 7}, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"];
allVertex = VertexList[graph];
cycleVertex = 
  FindCycle[graph,Infinity, All] /. a_ \[UndirectedEdge] b_ -> Sequence[a, b] // 
    Flatten // DeleteDuplicates;
deleteVertex = Complement[allVertex, cycleVertex];
VertexDelete[graph, deleteVertex ]
```

[image]